# Find $\|f\|^2$ in two ways

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, fourier-series

> Question: Consider the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)$ of
>   periodic measurable functions. Recall that it has a Hilbert space
>   basis consisting of functions  $\chi_n(x)=e^{2\pi i n x}$ where $n\in
> > \mathbb Z$. Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)$ be the periodic
>   function defined by $f(x)= x$, for $x\in [0,1)$. Compute  $||f||^2$ in
>   two ways, directly, and then using the Parseval's identity, i.e. using
>   the Fourier series expansion of $f$.

My attempt:
We have that $$\|f(x)\|^2 = \langle f, f \rangle = \int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 dx = \int_0^1 |x|^2 dx = \frac{|x|^3}{3}dx = \frac{1}{3}$$ since $x \in [0,1)$.

> I am not sure if this is right though. I feel like the norm should be
>   1...

Now, I will find the norm using Parseval's identity using the Fourier series expansion of $f$.
 By Parseval's, given the basis $\chi_n$ such that $\langle \chi_n, \chi_m \rangle=\delta_{n,m}$ like in our problem, we have that for every $x\in L^2(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ $$\sum_n |\langle x,\chi_n \rangle|=\|x\|^2$$
 For our problem, we have $f(x)=x$ for $x\in [0,1)$, thus we have that $$f(x)=x=\sum_n \langle x,\chi_n \rangle \chi_n$$ 
 $$\Rightarrow \|f(x)\|^2=\|x\|^2=\bigg(\|\sum_n \langle x,\chi_n \rangle \chi_n\|\bigg)^2$$

> I am not sure if this is right so far or how to continue from here.
>   Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In general, it is not a good practice to keep both $f(x)$ and $x$ to represent the identity function on $[0, 1)$. This might be causing some confusion. Try to use $f$ only to functions on your Hilbert space and $x$ as a dummy variable. Also, I think there are some typos above, like a square missing in the sum of Parseval identity

Comment: Your evaluation of $\lVert f \rVert^2$ is correct. For the second part, you should use a very similar reasoning, computing for each fixed $n$ the value of $\langle f, \chi_n \rangle$ by the definition of inner product on this space, that is, by computing an integral.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for your comments. I am getting The Fourier coefficients for are given by 
 $$a_n = \int_0^{1}f(x)e^{2\pi inx}dx=\int_0^{1}xe^{2\pi inx}dx $$ which gives $a_0=1/2$ and $a_n=1/(i\pi n)$. Now, from Parseval's, $$\|f\|^2=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|a_n|^2= 1/4 $$ But shouldn't it be the same norm for both methods?

Comment: It is the same norm. Notice the sum is not $\frac14$, this is only $|a_0|^2$. Since $|a_n| = |a_{-n}|$, what you actually get is
$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |a_n|^2 = \frac14 + \sum_{m \geq 1} \frac{2}{(2\pi m)^2} = \frac14 + \frac1{2\pi^2} \sum_{m \geq 1} \frac{1}{m^2}.
$$
Since $\lVert f \rVert^2 = \frac13$, this is equivalent to showing the famous result that $\sum_{m \geq 1} \frac{1}{m^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I appreciate it. I forgot I was taking the absolute value of all of them so that they don’t all cancel except the zeroth one.